# `ssh` fails to reach destination

Tags: bash, ssh, networking, file-transfer

I am trying to ssh to another machine in my lab using the IP address. The IP address is `137.84.4.211` and let's say the host name is `MyName`. My IP address is `137.82.81.10`. I don't know if this mean two computer share the same local host or not.

I tried

```
$ ssh -vv MyName@137.84.4.211
debug1: Reading configuration data /etc/ssh/ssh_config
debug1: /etc/ssh/ssh_config line 21: Applying options for *
debug2: ssh_connect: needpriv 0
debug1: Connecting to 137.84.4.211 [137.84.4.211] port 22.
debug1: connect to address 137.84.4.211 port 22: Operation timed out
ssh: connect to host 137.84.4.211 port 22: Operation timed out
```

Of course it took about a minute before return `Operation timed out`.

I also did

```
$ sudo tcptraceroute 137.84.4.211 22

Selected device en0, address 137.82.81.10, port 55360 for outgoing packets
Tracing the path to 137.84.4.211 on TCP port 22 (ssh), 30 hops max
 1  137.82.81.253  0.488 ms  0.370 ms  0.357 ms
 2  a0-a1.net.ubc.ca (142.103.78.250)  0.648 ms  0.660 ms  0.683 ms
 3  anguborder-a0.net.ubc.ca (137.82.123.137)  132.591 ms  1.959 ms  1.525 ms
 4  343-oran-cr1-ubcab.vncv1.bc.net (134.87.2.234)  0.549 ms  0.639 ms  0.625 ms
 5  cr1-bb3900.vantx1.bc.net (206.12.0.33)  0.747 ms  0.547 ms  0.620 ms
 6  vncv1rtr1.canarie.ca (205.189.32.172)  0.700 ms  1.426 ms  1.126 ms
 7  abilene-1-lo-jmb-706.sttlwa.pacificwave.net (207.231.240.8)  3.955 ms  4.010 ms  4.080 ms
 8  198.71.46.246  29.355 ms  29.405 ms  29.261 ms
 9  159.238.0.10  29.510 ms  29.404 ms  29.613 ms
10  159.238.0.9  32.455 ms  36.140 ms  32.574 ms
11  * * *
12  * * *
13  * * *
14  * * *
15  * * *
16  * * *
17  * * *
18  * * *
19  * * *
20  * * *
21  * * *
22  * * *
23  * * *
24  * * *
25  * * *
26  * * *
27  * * *
28  * * *
29  * * *
30  * * *
Destination not reached
```

As both computers are at Vancouver, BC (at less than 50 meters) I am a little surprise to see that it is searching through nodes in Ontario (205.189.32.172) and 
Wyoming (159.238.0.9).

I made sure the firewall is off and all connections are allowed. Both computers run on Mac OS X El Capitan

Comment: packets are being dropped somewhere between your host and the intended target. You can use "tcptraceroute 137.84.4.211 22" to find out where.

Comment: 137.84 is at U. Wyoming, 137.82 is at UBC. If you're at UBC, you probably should give your computers either UBC addresses or private addresses (192.168.x.y, 10.x).

Comment: So, should I go to the target computer and change the IP address?

Comment: Yes. Do you have network administrators who assign addresses to you?

Comment: Ok, done. The address changed to 137.82... Good. I thought it would fix it but now I get `connection refused` :( Maybe we should consider this post as being solved (you can make an answer from your comment) and I open another post for `connection refused`. What do you think?

Comment: silly question but, does the user name not exist on the target machine? Do you have bad ssh keys setup?

Comment: connection refused means the service is not running or is running in another port

Comment: You sometimes get it if you said yes to add a server to the known host list and for some reason the keys that were added to the knownhost file have changed for some reason.

Comment: @Rob Yes, I am sure the username exists (and it is a simple one without space or anything). I don't know much about ssh keys setup though.

Comment: @Rob I deleted the knownhost list but it doesn't change anything.

Comment: Ok, I found out. Thanks a lot everybody for your help. Remote login were disabled. I had to go to System `Preferences -> Sharing, enable Remote Login`.

Comment: I think someone (@MarkPlotnick for example) could make an answer out of his comment as it solved the bad IP address (which was the first issue). What do you think? Or should I just delete my post?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The IP-addresses 137.`84`.4.211 and 137.`82`.81.10 are not on the same network. Most likely, it should be either 84 or 82 in both of the addresses.